# Error while running poseNet on Webcam video

Tags: javascript, html, tensorflow.js

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs"></script>
  <!-- Load Posenet -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow-models/posenet"></script>
  <title>Yoga Pose Assessment Through Webcam</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <video id="video" width="640" height="640" autoplay playsinline style=" -moz-    transform: scaleX(-1);
  -o-transform: scaleX(-1);
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1);
  transform: scaleX(-1);
  ;"</video>
  </div>
  <script>

    // Load camera
    async function setupCamera() {
      if (!navigator.mediaDevices || !navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
        throw new Error(
          'Browser API navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia not available');
      }

      const video = document.getElementById('video');
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        'audio': false,
        'video': true,
      });
      video.srcObject = stream;

      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        video.onloadedmetadata = () => {
          resolve(video);
        };
      });
    }

    async function loadVideo() {
      const video = await setupCamera();
      video.play();

      //return video;
    }

    async function detect() {

      let video;
      video = await loadVideo();

      let net;
      // Load posenet
      net = await posenet.load();

      flipHorizontal = true;

      // Scale the image. The smaller the faster
      const imageScaleFactor = 0.75;

      // Stride, the larger, the smaller the output, the faster
      const outputStride = 32;

      // Store all the poses
      let poses = [];
      let minPoseConfidence;
      let minPartConfidence;

      const pose = await net.estimateSinglePose(video,
        imageScaleFactor,
        flipHorizontal,
        outputStride);
      console.log(pose);
    }

    detect();

  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run the above code in Firefox I get the following error

```
TypeError: t is undefined   posenet:17:10511
```

When I run the above code in google chrome I get the following error

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'height' of undefined
at U (posenet:17)
at t.<anonymous> (posenet:17)
at posenet:17
at Object.next (posenet:17)
at posenet:17
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at u (posenet:17)
at t.estimateSinglePose (posenet:17)
at detect (demo.html:106)
```

I am trying to log the pose object. I am using the video taken from the webcam and is passed to poseNet.
I would also like to know if the approach I am using is good or there are any changes to be made.

While displaying the webcam video to the user I am flipping the video using css and again while passing the video to poseNet I am setting the flipHorizontal to true. Is the approach correct?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's a missing `>` in your video element.

Comment: I dont think that caused the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try uncommenting the return in `loadVideo`:

```js
async function loadVideo() {
  const video = await setupCamera();
  video.play();

  return video;
}
```

also update the `video` tag as mentioned by `@cherryblossom`:

```html
<video id="video" width="640" height="640" autoplay playsinline
      style="-moz-o-transform: scaleX(-1); -webkit-transform: scaleX(-1); transform: scaleX(-1);"></video>
```